# How to logout from all devices if authentication provider is Microsoft.Owin

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, owin

Logging out a user's session has always worked for me without problems, by using the `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Signout()` method.

However, a user might have loggedin from at least a dozen different devices (phone, tablet, other PCs, etc).

I want to implement that when the user changes his password, to force a logout on all other devices except the device where the user did the change of password.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using  ASP.NET Identity 2, you can use `UpdateSecurityStampAsync` and then set `OnValidateIdentity` in the `CookieAuthenticationOptions` settings

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    { 
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
...
}
```

Then after changing password successfully:

```
signInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignOut();     

//updating the security stamp invalidates all other sessions
await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(currentUser.Id);

await signInManager.SignInAsync(currentUser, false, false);
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I was doing the UpdateSecurityStampAsync call. However, I missed the OnValidateIdentity in the Provider.

I did have some troubles though (maybe you can assist me somehow). I indeed used validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0). Login was successful, but right after navigating on a second page, cookie would get lost (so that way, only 1 page navigation would have been possible.
I changed the timespan to something larger and instead made some check of my own for the presence and equality of the SecurityStamp. Should it really work with timespan 0 ?